# Wordpress Custom classes for different pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I have unique theme for WP and I need to add different classes into tag body if user come to these pages. (Example for example.com/bonuses/ I need tag body with class ="body page_body" for example.com/news/ I need tag body with class ="body page_news" )   How can I get it ? 
In Internet I found tip like - 
write in functions.php

```
function my_body_class_filter( $classes ) {
global $post;

if ( $post ) {
    $classes[] = $post->post_name;
}

return $classes;
```

}
   add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_body_class_filter' );

and in header.php

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>
```

But I got a lot of classes https://prnt.sc/jtn3pf I don't need so many classes. Can someone recommend a filter by slug for pages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want other classes then you need to remove `<?php body_class(); ?>` from  tag.

And add your custom class directly using below way.

```
 $classname="body";
 global $post;
 $classname. = " page_".$post->post_name;

 <body <?php echo $classname; ?>>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use this option because I have the cyrillic name in post_name http://prntscr.com/ju6m8y and this will be look ugly

Comment: Then you can do one thing in your page create one custom field which called class and use that instead of page name.